# Why does Get User Access token throws invalid_grant error?

Tags: azure, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using [Microsoft Graph Postman Collections](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections) to test common Microsoft Graph APIs from within Postman. However, I am stuck while trying to **fetch user access token**

Below is the request

```js
POST /7c69806f-5754-488f-9dd8-7daa8afea4fd/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
SdkVersion: postman-graph/v1.0
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ac512133-5afe-47a3-ae9b-3b6c0b510ebd
grant_type=passwordclient_id=ebbe4872-5b7187-de6d6ddf7301client_secret=g99p8DWoxdUPY-%3F%40%5Bv7kt2g4BMxGscope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.defaultuserName=rohitdhamijagmail.onmicrosoft.compassword=Zcost%4080
```

On trying "Fetch user access token" POST API, I get following error:

```js
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50034: The user account rohitdhamijagmail.onmicrosoft.com does not exist in the 7c69806f-5754-488f-9dd8-7daa8afea4fd directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: c0e97dd8-053d-4c99-81e4-354d7ae7d500\r\nCorrelation ID: 7e67450e-3054-48bc-b808-2f6277093dac\r\nTimestamp: 2020-03-03 09:38:09Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50034
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-03-03 09:38:09Z",
    "trace_id": "c0e97dd8-053d-4c99-81e4-354d7ae7d500",
    "correlation_id": "7e67450e-3054-48bc-b808-2f6277093dac",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50034"
}
```

The user account does show under my tenant in Azure , below is the image attached
[image]

What can be the issue?
**Note:** I have configured the global environments properly, since I am able to use other API's like  Get User info etc.

Comment: Include your token request part in question as well.

Comment: watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tg-OBdv_8o

Comment: @ziedbenothman it did not help for this issue. Few users have posted the same issue under his youtube thread.

Comment: but this video it's working , i verified that with my self

Comment: you should be try to do that

Comment: ok can you please confirm two things for me 1. what is the grant_type you used 2. what was the userid you used?

Comment: i am using POSTMAN

Comment: Please follow the steps accordingly hope you would get token successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Request Should be Like this.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:b603c7be_Client_id_e61f925
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:NpmwO/KDJ_client_secret:NpmwO_W0kWf1SbnL
username:tenentUser.onmicrosoft.com
password:YourUserPassword
grant_type:password
```

See the screen shot:

[image]

I am getting token as expected

***`Step: 1`***

[image]

***`Step: 2`***

[image]

***`Step: 3`***

[image]

***`Note:`***

> 1. Make sure your user belong to azure portal on your tenant
> 2. Your Client Id belongs to that tenant
> 3. Application secret is valid or not expired.

***`Update: How to get Tenant Id`***

[image]

For more information you could refer [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Hope that would help.

Comment: can you please confirm the permissions you provided?

Comment: also i see that in tenant, you gave xyz.onmicrosoft.com -- if i append .onmicrosoft.com then i get error: error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS90002: Tenant '7c69806f-5754-488f-9dd8-7daa8afea4fd.onmicrosoft.com' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.\r\nTrace ID: 1587fa4a-bd99-41b6-98da-4be7b5f73700\r\nCorrelation ID: 850db963-bb15-48cc-ba5e-edec72a25314\r\nTimestamp: 2020-03-03 11:11:26Z",
    "error_codes": [
        90002

Comment: I applied everything as mentioned, but still the same error.

Comment: Perfect, the issue is resolved. thanks for the very detailed steps!!!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and it worked for me without any issue, couple of points that can be looked at are,

1. Either the app must be registered under same active directory OR it has multi-tenant enabled like below, [Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFCAX.png)
2. The app should have following permissions, [Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsjEr.png)
3. I just updated user name and password in postman call and my account is also on **yourdomainhere.onmicrosoft.com** [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig4Ar.png)