# Calling an Microsoft Graph API for token gives error "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am calling a Graph API URL

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

to get an access token but I am getting the following response.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 5ff6b053-9011-4397-89ff-fdb6f31e4600\r\nCorrelation ID: 22509847-199d-4bd8-a083-b29d8bbf3139\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-01 11:14:00Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-04-01 11:14:00Z",
    "trace_id": "5ff6b053-9011-4397-89ff-fdb6f31e4600",
    "correlation_id": "22509847-199d-4bd8-a083-b29d8bbf3139",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

I have an active tenantid, I have an application registered, and I have an active user for the above application say `user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`; that user has ALL the roles (Global Administrator).

Please find below Postman's request and Response.
[PostmanSnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzrtV.png)

Also I have given API permission as suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Show us the post body for your token call

Comment: Include your token request in question or add [which token protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504256/why-does-get-user-access-token-throws-invalid-grant-error/60505713#60505713) you are using. Additionally, you should have [required permission on Graph API on azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777789/permissions-to-add-member-to-group-via-graph-api/60777953#60777953).

Comment: Added Request and Response body

Comment: @Walmikk Have look on the answer and try in given format. Hope that would resolved your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Problem:*** I have successfully reproduced your error. As you seen below:

[image]

***Solution:***

You are trying in wrong way. You have to send required parameter in `form-data` on postman with `key-value pairs` like below format:

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:b6695c7be_YourClient_Id_e6921e61f659
client_secret:Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf_Your_Secret_Yp8ns4sc=
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
  //Token Request End Point
    string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "b6695c7be_YourClient_Id_e6921e61f659",
        ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf_Your_Secret_Yp8ns4sc=",
        ["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" 
    });

    dynamic json;
    AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

    json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
```

**Class Used:**

```cs
public class AccessTokenClass
   {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
   }
```

You could refer to [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Hope that would help. If you still have any concern feel free to share.

Comment: Thanks...It works when passing data as FormUrlEncodedContent.

Comment: Glad to help you.