# In Azure Active Directory authentication why is authorisation code flow used

Tags: c#, azure

I am working on a .net MVC and web API project and using active directory to authenticate users to API, on authentication, a code is being returned from AD and I have to exchange the code to obtain a token and use that token to call the API, the question is why is the code returned and why do I have to exchange it for the token? can I directly obtain a token?

Comment: Yes there are some other authentication protocol where you can call token directly without exchanging code or user intersection [client_credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970010/calling-an-microsoft-graph-api-for-token-gives-error-aadsts900144-the-request/60972749#60972749) is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all because of security reasons.

OAuth 2.0 wanted to meet these two criteria:

- All developers will not have an SSL enabled server and you should allow them to use non-HTTPS redirect URI
- You don't want hackers to be able to steal access/refresh tokens by intercepting requests.

Since the Authorization Code grant has the extra step of exchanging the authorization code for the access token, it provides an additional layer of security not present in the Implicit grant type.

According to Nate Barbettini we want the extra step of exchanging the authentication code for the access token, because the authentication code can be used in the front channel (less secure), and the access token can be used in the back channel (more secure).

Thus, the security benefit is that the access token isn't exposed to the browser, and thus cannot be intercepted/grabbed from a browser. We trust the web server more, which communicates via back channels. The access token, which is secret, can then remain on the web server, and not be exposed to the browser (i.e. front channels).

For more information, watch this fantastic video:

OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (in plain English) https://youtu.be/996OiexHze0?t=26m30s (Start 26 mins)

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, just what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really specific to Azure AD, and is more about the OAuth flow and why it is used.
The flow seems a bit complex, and well, it is, but there are reasons for all the things it does.

I encourage you to use authorization code flow instead of other approaches.
It has many advantages:

- Your app will never see the user's password
- The user cannot see your app's client secret
- The user cannot see your app's access tokens (and neither can a man-in-the-middle attacker)
- You get a refresh token that you can use to get new tokens whenever needed (you do need to specify the offline_access scope for this though)
- The user can go through multi-factor authentication, federated authentication with ADFS etc., and your app doesn't need to care about that

Alternative flows and their downsides:

- Implicit flow

  - Gives you a token directly without the code exchange
  - There is no refresh token
  - Mainly used in Single Page Apps, where refresh is done using a hidden iframe, but that depends on the user's session remaining active
  - If you use this outside a SPA, you can't really refresh the token, requiring the user to login again every hour
  - User can see and take your app's access tokens
- Client credentials flow

  - Instead of accessing the API as a user, you access it as the app itself
  - Some APIs do not support this approach and require you to make calls on behalf of a user
  - This doesn't allow you to authenticate a user
  - Application permissions are needed to use this flow, which usually give very broad access to the entire organization
  - The upside of this flow is that it is very simple
- Resource Owner Password Credentials flow

  - **Do not use this flow**
  - HTTP request to token endpoint with app + user credentials
  - Exposes user password to your app (!)
  - Does not work if user has MFA, expired password etc.