# Azure How to get grant_type value?

Tags: azure, oauth, openid-connect

I am using this URL to fetch the token.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/4f8fa257-36c3-4e8c-887f-0dde6fc8f1fe/oauth2/v2.0/token

All other values are properly placed but only issue I find with grant_type
so can anyone help finding the grant_type value.
A hint a image I am going to attach but it's not clear.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/media/v2-saml-bearer-assertion/6.png

Can anyone help finding the grant_type from following image.

Comment: You cannot get token from URL request. grant_type is a type of protocol you want to use to generate token. Please refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970010/calling-an-microsoft-graph-api-for-token-gives-error-aadsts900144-the-request/60972749#60972749)

Comment: Hello,
I gone through the example you mentioned but actually it didn't solve my query.
Let me try to explain it more in detail.
please check this below screenshot
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1EzxRMKZI2OAU8vUOqlncVWyRx3JJ8P4s
Now I am using grant type as per screenshot it giving error.
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1njhB4wXRqeAsTlyo5yU2lNEgKYov8Pui
according to document it should have client_credentials
But I am actually not able to under the exact value what should I enter here.
Can you help me in this?

Comment: Have you got the assertion value?

Comment: Currently I am passing Assertion only in the value?
Can you please guide from where I get assertion value?

Comment: Are you trying on-premises azure active directory?

Comment: Sorry, I am little new this setup. But not sure what it means?
From where I can get that information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210858/discussion-between-user3884077-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).